# jQuery defaulting back to original CSS on mouseout

Tags: jquery

I am currently using the following:

```
$("li.nav-shop-sub").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("is-active");
    $("li.is-active a").next().css( "background-color", "red" );
});
```

however it leaves the background colour as red even after the user stops hovering over the li and the is-active class is removed. How can I get the background colour back to default on moouseout?

HTML:

```
<li class="nav-shop-sub">
  <a href="link">link</a>
  <div class="grid nav-shop-wrapper has-product-noms">
    <ul class="grid-item list-stacked link-list">
     <li><a href="link">link</a></li>
     <li><a href="link">link</a></li>
     <li><a href="link">link</a></li>
     <li><a href="link"link</a></li>
     <li><a href="link">link</a></li>
     <li><a href="link">link</a></li>
     <li><a href="link">link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: can you add your html/css code too?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the `hover()` event It doesn't work so that it does something on `mousein` and reverse on `mouseout`. It does the SAME function you have specified on the BOTH events. In other words your code changes the background to red twice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my example working:

http://jsfiddle.net/washington_guedes/mc9apah9/

---

```
$("li a").hover(function(){

    /* do something to this li */
    $(this/*a*/).parent(/*li*/).toggleClass("active");

    /* do something to this a */
    $(this/*a*/).toggleClass("active");

    /* do something to the next a */
    $(this/*a*/).next(/*a*/).toggleClass("bgRed");

});
```

Comment: I dont want the css toggled when hovering over the div. The div will change colour when the previous li is hovered over.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a callback function on your `hover()` like this:

```
$("li.nav-shop-sub").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("is-active");
        $("li.is-active a").next().addClass('red');
    },
    function() {
        $("li.is-active a").next().removeClass('red');
    }
);
```

**CSS:**

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

More information on [hover jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Answer (score 0):

You can just put your background-color on class .is-active

```
li.nav-shop-sub.is-active a {
    background-color: red;
}
```

And in the JS, just toggle the class:

```
$("li.nav-shop-sub").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("is-active");    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- actually, .hover() in jquery not working like :hover in css
- if you want to use .hover() in jquery you should use toggle for
  everything
- Or you can use .mouseenter() then .mouseleave() to return your values
  back